# pow says: Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, rack-pow

I have a rails app that runs fine with `rails s`, but when I try to load it using pow I'm getting this error:

```
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `block in materialize'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:82:in `map!'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:82:in `materialize'
....
```

Weird thing is, the .rvmrc file in this app specifies `1.9.3-p125`:

```
which rake
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rake
```

and here's what I see when I run `bundle install`:

```
Using rake (0.9.2.2)
```

FWIW, pow works just fine with another non-rails project using 1.9.2 and a different gemset.

Thanks!

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I guess you updated RVM and run into this known issue: https://github.com/37signals/pow/issues/271

the easiest solution is to run it in project dir:

```
rvm env . > .powenv
```

OR:

```
cd /project/path # with .rvmrc
rvm env > .powenv
```

Comment: I got "Unrecognized command line argument(s): '. ' ( see: 'rvm usage' )" when I ran this command.

Comment: what version of RVM are you using? update it and it should work just fine.

Comment: rvm 1.9.2, "You already have the latest version!" when I did "rvm get latest", thanks.

Comment: that's old one, you need to update with `rvm get head` or just run the installer `curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`, make sure to run once `rvm reload` after updating.

Comment: thanks, but i am still getting this error after i upgraded to  1.14.5.

Comment: It should be `rvm env -- ruby-1.9.3-p194 > .powenv`. If you have a gemset then put `rvm env -- ruby-1.9.3-p194@gemset > .powenv `

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this issue when I changed from .rvmrc to .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset files.

Change your .powrc file to be:

```
if [ -f "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm" ] && [ -f ".ruby-version" ] && [ -f ".ruby-gemset" ]; then
  source "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm"
  rvm use `cat .ruby-version`@`cat .ruby-gemset`
fi
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using RVM you have to add a file named ".powenv" at the root of your project as described here :

http://rvm.io/integration/pow

Answer (score 3):

I've been using this .powrc which nicely covers all bases:

```
if [ -f "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm" ]; then
  source "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm"

  if [ -f ".rvmrc" ]; then
    source ".rvmrc"
  fi

  if [ -f ".ruby-version" ]; then
    rvm use `cat .ruby-version`
  fi

  if [ -f ".ruby-gemset" ]; then
    rvm gemset use --create `cat .ruby-gemset`
  fi
fi
```

Taken from here https://gist.github.com/nbibler/5307941 (thanks nbibler!)