# POW/Rails error: Error starting applicationBundler::GemNotFound: Could not find minitest-4.7.5 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, ruby-on-rails-4, rack-pow

I just had to remove RVM and reinstall, and then installed Ruby 2.0.0

I can run rails console from command line in the project, but can't get it to load in the browser.

I was reading through some answers on here about .bash_profile and .bashrc and neither existed in my ~ folder. I tried messing with the .bashrc file but nothing helps.

In my .bashrc:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

rvm list:

```
=* ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]
```

rails -v

```
Rails 4.0.0
```

Now when i try to start my application I see this:

> Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find minitest-4.7.5 in any of the
>   sources
>       /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in
>   `block in materialize'
>       /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in`
>   map!'
>       /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in
>   `materialize'
>       /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in`
>   specs'
>       /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in
>   `specs_for'
>       /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:148:in`
>   requested_specs'
>       /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in
>   `requested_specs'
>       /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in`
>   setup'
>       /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in
>   `setup'
>       /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in`
>   '
>       /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:116:in
>   `require'
>       /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:116:in`
>   rescue in require'
>       /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:122:in
>   `require'
>       ~/Sites/projectname/config/boot.rb:4:in`'
>       /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in
>   `require'
>       /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in`
>   require'
>       ~/Sites/projectname/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
>       /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in`
>   require'
>       /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in
>   `require'
>       ~/Sites/projectname/config/environment.rb:2:in`'
>       /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in
>   `require'
>       /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in`
>   require'
>       ~/Sites/projectname/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
>       ~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/builder.rb:4:in`
>   instance_eval'
>       ~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/builder.rb:4:in
>   `initialize'
>       ~/Sites/projectname/config.ru:1:in`new'
>       ~/Sites/projectname/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
>       ~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:50:in`
>   eval'
>       ~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:50:in
>   `load_config'
>       ~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:43:in`
>   initialize'
>       ~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:13:in
>   `new'
>       ~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:13:in`
>   run'
>       ~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/bin/nack_worker:4:in
>   `'

rvm info:

```
system:
    uname:       "**** 11.4.2 Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
    system:      "osx/10.7/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11)"
    zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 4.3.11 (i386-apple-darwin11.0)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.22.3 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "3 days 23 hours 28 minutes 44 seconds ago"
    path:         "/usr/local/rvm"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.0.0p247"
    date:         "2013-06-27"
    platform:     "x86_64-darwin11.4.2"
    patchlevel:   "2013-06-27 revision 41674"
    full_version: "ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247"
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247"
    GEM_PATH:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247"
    IRBRC:        "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

bundle:

```
Using: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@projectgemfile
mac:project joel$ bundle install
Using rake (10.1.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.5) 
Using minitest (4.7.5) 
Using multi_json (1.7.9) 
Using atomic (1.1.13) 
Using thread_safe (0.1.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.37) 
Using activesupport (4.0.0) 
Using builder (3.1.4) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using rack (1.5.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using actionpack (4.0.0) 
Using mime-types (1.24) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.15) 
Using mail (2.5.4) 
Using actionmailer (4.0.0) 
Using activemodel (4.0.0) 
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3) 
Using arel (4.0.0) 
Using activerecord (4.0.0) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3) 
Using execjs (2.0.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using thor (0.18.1) 
Using railties (4.0.0) 
Using coffee-rails (4.0.0) 
Using multipart-post (1.2.0) 
Using faraday (0.8.8) 
Using hashie (2.0.5) 
Using hike (1.2.3) 
Using httpauth (0.2.0) 
Using jbuilder (1.5.1) 
Using jquery-rails (3.0.4) 
Using json (1.8.0) 
Using jwt (0.1.8) 
Using oauth2 (0.8.1) 
Using omniauth (1.1.4) 
Using omniauth-oauth2 (1.0.3) 
Using omniauth-facebook (1.4.0) 
Using pg (0.16.0) 
Using bundler (1.3.5) 
Using tilt (1.4.1) 
Using sprockets (2.10.0) 
Using sprockets-rails (2.0.0) 
Using rails (4.0.0) 
Using rdoc (3.12.2) 
Using sass (3.2.10) 
Using sass-rails (4.0.0) 
Using sdoc (0.3.20) 
Using turbolinks (1.3.0) 
Using uglifier (2.2.0) 
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure you set up integration for RVM / Pow correctly?

Both projects show example how to do this, although the RVM one is more complete: http://rvm.io/integration/pow#using-rvm-with-pow - I'm not pasting here the code as the site will be updated if needed.

Comment: i needed a .powrc file in my project.

Answer (score 1):

you need to run:

```
bundle install
```

it will ensure all gems required by application are available for it

Comment: i ran bundle, its showing all gems in my gemset for the project

Comment: yep. i will post up the bundle output when i get home to that machine. I am using RVM and .rvmrc file, so shouldn't this line say my gem name after the ruby version: **Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find minitest-4.7.5 in any of the sources /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247** @GEMSETNAMEHERE

Comment: added output of bundle to my question.

Comment: I can run rails console from command lines.. so i'm not sure if this is POW or what

Answer (score 1):

Per this link regarding [bundler version 1.5.0](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2780), you should upgrade your bundler to version 1.5.1 to fix a nasty little bug that surfaces with default gems in Ruby 1.9 and 2.0. I simply ran ***gem update bundler*** before running ***bundle install*** and everything seems fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10312179/983921) worked for me.

`rvm env . > .powenv`

Answer (score 0):

try adding `.rvcrc` in the applications's root directory with:

```
rvm 2.0.0
```

or below if you use different gemset:

```
rvm 2.0.0@rails4  # replace rails4 with your gemset
```

you can see more information in http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_2.3.2