# Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find net-ssh-2.7.0 in any of the sources

Tags: deployment, ssh, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, bundler

I've added capistrano to my Gemfile. After running the bundle command I get the following Error:

`Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find net-ssh-2.7.0 in any of the sources`

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.1'

# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end


gem 'simple_form'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'less-rails'
gem 'therubyracer'

gem "liquid"

gem "devise"
gem "devise-basecamper"
gem "cancan"
gem 'userstamp', git: 'git://github.com/andrezimpel/userstamp.git'



# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano'
end

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

When I remove `gem 'capistrano'` everything works fine!

I'm not sure where the problem is, I hope somebody could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `rvm env . > .powenv` worked for me.

Seems that pow made me some trouble.

cc: [pow says: Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304405/pow-says-bundlergemnotfound-could-not-find-rake-0-9-2-2-in-any-of-the-source)